# SSH tunneling commands for better security and privacy

Tags: wireless-networking, ssh, security, ssh-tunnel, sniffing

i have a centos 6 VPS.

- I use `ssh -p 443 -D 8080 -f -C -N root@ip`  on mac terminal for SSH tunneling but with wireshark when i sniff my traffic i can see DNS requests are not encrypted ! (i use proxifier to cover my all traffic thru socks proxy). how i can secure DNS requests and UDP traffic by SSH tunnel ?
- Also how can i disable SSH logs (it log all IP addresses using SSH) ? and how to remove old logs ?

Comment: You might be better off in breaking this up into multiple quesitons. 1. How do I secure my DNS quereies, 2. How can I disable SSH logs, for example.

Comment: Also you shouldn't really cross post questions on multiple stackexchange websites, it's discouraged! http://serverfault.com/questions/461237/ssh-tunneling-commands-for-dns-forwarding

Answer (score 2):

#### SSH tunnels aren't VPNs

First and foremost, let me say say that you should install OpenVPN (or similar) on your VPS and save you a lot of headaches. When connected to a VPN, you can easily make sure that *all* traffic will get routed through it.

**DNS requests**

Normally, DNS requests do not get routed through the proxy. Your ISP is (supposed to be) your DNS server, and there's no need for it.

You can specify a local address as your DNS server (system wide), e.g., `127.0.0.3` and set up port forwarding to a suitable DNS server:

```
ssh -p 443 -D 8080 -L 127.0.0.3:53:8.8.8.8:53 -f -C -N root@ip
```

Some applications also let you specify this. In Firefox, e.g., all you have to do is enter `about:config` set `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` to `true`

#### Logging

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, change the line

```
LogLevel INFO
```

to

```
LogLevel QUIET
```

This prevents `sshd` from sending data to the system log.

However, other processes might still log your IP address. For example, [lastlog](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lastlog) and [last](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?last) both store IP addresses you logged in from (using SSH is asically logging in)  `/var/log/lastlog` and `/var/log/wtmp`, respectively.

If you're really that worried about logs, you can erase all files in `/var/log` periodically. But keep in mind that if somebody gets access to your VPS, he probably can get access to the purchase information as well.

Comment: what about ssh -w  vpn ? (openvpn blocked by my isp)

Comment: Tunneling the VPN traffic through SSH might work, but I haven't tried it and I'm not sure how to accomplish it. Unless your ISP does deep packet inspection (since port 443 works for SSH, there a chance it doesn't), you can configure your VPN to use a well-known port as well. Make sure your SSH server listens to a different port if you try 443 for the VPN!